# CKEDITOR перестает отображаться на странице

Tags: python, html, django, ckeditor

Помогите пожалуйста. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Не логично.

Когда из settings я удаляю строку `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/'` у меня отображается CKEDITOR с некоторыми функциями (хоть и не со всеми что мне нужны) но стоит мне добавить строку `KEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/'` и CKEDITOR перестает отображаться на странице.
Кто то может сказать: удали просто строку и пусть отображается. Но. Во первых, мне не нравится что работает не логично и не правильно. Во вторых, `static\ckeditor\build\ckeditor.js` я разместил для того, что бы были функции (разные шрифты, размеры и пр.) которых сейчас нету.
дальше код в моих html, views, models...

у меня ckeditor в:

```
D:\Сайт\...\static\ckeditor\package.json 
D:\Сайт\...\static\ckeditor\webpack.config.js 
D:\Сайт\...\static\ckeditor\src 
D:\Сайт\...\static\ckeditor\sample 
D:\Сайт\...\static\ckeditor\build 
D:\Сайт\...\static\ckeditor\build\ckeditor.js
```

У меня в settings:

```py
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'main',
'catalog.apps.CatalogConfig',
'users',
'ckeditor',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'dal',
'dal_select2',
'widget_tweaks',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.apple',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
'django.contrib.sites',
'debug_toolbar',

]
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'catalog', 'static'),
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'main', 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# Media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/' #путь для загрузки файлов

CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/catalog/ckeditor/' #путь к статическим файлам CKEditor
```

В html:

```html
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<script src="{% static 'ckeditor/build/ckeditor.js' %}"></script>
<div id="editor"></div>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.media }}
<div class="form-group">
{{ form.title.label_tag }}
{{ form.title }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ form.content.label_tag }}
{{ form.content }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ form.file.label_tag }}
{{ form.file }}
</div>


<button type="submit">Загрузить</button>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

views:

````py
class ChapterDetail(DetailView):
    model = Chapter
    
    template_name = 'catalog/chapter_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'chapter'
    
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
    
            book_slug = self.kwargs.get('book_slug')
            chapter_slug = self.kwargs.get('chapter_slug')
    
            if book_slug is not None and chapter_slug is not None:
                return get_object_or_404(queryset, book__slug=book_slug, slug=chapter_slug)

        raise AttributeError("Book slug and chapter slug expected in the URL pattern")
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CommentForm() # add this line
        return context


class ChapterCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView):
    model = Chapter
    form_class = ChapterForm
    template_name = 'catalog/chapter_form.html'
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        book_slug = self.kwargs['book_slug']
        book = get_object_or_404(Book, slug=book_slug)
        form.instance.book = book
    
        # If a file was uploaded
        if form.instance.file:
            try:
                # Read the file and put its content into the 'content' field
                file_content = form.instance.file.read().decode('utf-8')
                form.instance.content = file_content
            except Exception as e:
                messages.error(self.request, f"Error reading file: {str(e)}")
                return super().form_invalid(form)
        elif not form.instance.content:
            messages.error(self.request, "You must provide chapter content or upload a file.")
            return super().form_invalid(form)
    
    return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def test_func(self):
        # test_func проверяет, выполняется ли условие для данного пользователя
        # Если пользователь в группе 'Перекладач', он может создать главу
    
        return self.request.user.groups.filter(name='Перекладач').exists()
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        book_slug = self.object.book.slug # здесь мы получаем slug из созданной главы
        chapter_slug = self.object.slug
        return reverse('catalog:chapter_detail', kwargs={'book_slug': book_slug, 'chapter_slug': chapter_slug})

forms:

```py
class ChapterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    content = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'file']

        help_texts = {
                      'file': 'You can upload a text file instead of typing in the content.',
        }
````

models:

```py
class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey('catalog.Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_chapters')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = RichTextField(config_name='extends', blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='chapters/', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=False, null=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

urls:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('main.urls')),
path('catalog/', include(('catalog.urls', 'catalog'), namespace='catalog')),
path('users/', include(('users.urls', 'users'), namespace='users')),
path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')) #текстовый редактор CKEditor
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA
```

Comment: Я добавил отступы в код, посмотрите, может быть что-нибудь не правильно.